# Mac keeps booting into disk utilities

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, utilities

my mac kept getting stuck on the apple logo when booting up so I went into recovery mode and formatted the disk and installed OS X again. But for some reason it is not booting normally when I switch it on it boots automatically into disk utilities??

Comment: Will it boot to the regular drive if you select it at boot time by holding the opt/alt key? If so, then System Prefs > Startup Disk [unlock] > Select your regular disk, Restart...

Answer (score 1):

When you say "boots automatically into disk utilities" do you see this screen?

[image: OS X Utilities selection screen]

If so, try closing the window by either pressing the Command and Q keys simultaneously or by clicking the red button in the top left corner of the window. It should prompt you to either shut down, restart, or select a startup disk. Choose to select a startup disk, then chose "Macintosh HD" (unless when you erased your disk and installed OS X again you replaced Macintosh HD with another name, in which case you should select that disk instead). Then click "Restart".